# How can I use internal mutability with generic type in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, composition, interior-mutability

I would like to design a struct in Rust that can be constructed with an object that implements the `Digest` trait, and abstract the behavior of the hash behind a method. Here's a simple example that doesn't compile:

```rust
use digest::Digest;

struct Crypto<D: Digest> {
    digest: D,
}

impl<D> Crypto<D>
where
    D: Digest,
{
    pub fn hash(&self, data: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
        self.digest.chain(&data).finalize_reset().to_vec()
    }
}
```

This fails to compile because `self` is immutably borrowed in the method signature, so `self.digest` cannot be immutably borrowed. So it tries to copy it, instead, but since the `D` generic is not defined to adhere to the `Copy` trait, it fails.

I'd rather not copy it, anyway. I'd rather have the one instance. Some things I've tried:

- Changing the method signature to take `mut self` instead. But that moves ownership of the object into the method, after which it cannot be used again.
- Wrapping the `digest` field in a `RefMut` or `Cell`, in an effort to adopt [internal mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html), but I was not able to figure out the right method to then borrow the `digest` mutably without it trying to copy the value. Also, would prefer to keep borrow checks at compile-time if possible.
- Change the type of `D` to a function that returns an instance of a `Digest`, and use it to instantiate a new digest inside the `hash()` method. But then, even if I define it as `D: Box<dyn Digest>`, the compiler complains that `the value of the associated type OutputSize (from trait digest::Digest) must be specified`. So that seems challenging, since I want to support different hashing algorithms that will produce hashes of varying sizes.

I was trying to use generics to get the compile-time benefits of trait bounds, but have to admit that the challenges of internal mutability when composing with objects whose behavior require mutability is thwarting me. Pointers to idiomatic Rust solutions to this design challenge greatly appreciated.

Bonus — how do I avoid the `to_vec()` copy and just return [the array returned by `finalize_reset()`](https://docs.rs/digest/0.9.0/digest/trait.Digest.html#tymethod.finalize_reset)?

Comment: `chain` requires you to move `digest`, so what do you plan on doing to replace the old `digest` with?

Comment: Well I could do away with `chain`. But `self.digest.update(&data); self.digest.finalize_reset().to_vec()` still wants to borrow `digest` as immutable, and can't.

Comment: After getting rid of the `chain` function you can update `hash`'s method signature to take `&mut self` instead of `&self` and that seems to meet all of your requirements, no?

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't realize `chain` wanted to move `digest`, so removing that *and* changing the signature to `mut &self` does indeed fix it, as long as I also create the Crypto object as mutable. Would be nice to keep it internal, though.

Comment: @theory Can you please clarify what you mean by "would be nice to keep it internal"? Is it a strong requirement that all `Crypto` instances remain immutable or... you want people to be able to call `hash` even on an immutable `Crypto`?

Comment: Yes, the latter. The user of this module shouldn't have to care that a buffer is allocated and freed in order to do the hashing, though I recognize that `update` requires the strut itself to maintain state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd rather not copy it, anyway. I'd rather have the one instance [of `self.digest`].

The problem is that `self.digest.chain()` *consumes* (takes ownership of) `self.digest`, and that's a fundamental part of the contract of `Digest::chain()` which you cannot change. Interior mutability won't help because it's not a mutability issue, it's an object lifetime issue - you cannot use an object after it is moved or dropped.

Your idea to make `digest` a function that creates digests should work, though. It will require two generic types, one for the digest type, with a trait bound of `Digest`, and the other for the factory, with a trait bound of `Fn() -> D`:

```
struct Crypto<F> {
    digest_factory: F,
}

impl<D, F> Crypto<F>
where
    D: Digest,
    F: Fn() -> D,
{
    pub fn hash(&self, data: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
        (self.digest_factory)()
            .chain(&data)
            .finalize()  // use finalize as the object is not reused
            .to_vec()
    }
}
```

> how do I avoid the `to_vec()` copy and just return the array returned by `finalize_reset()`?

You can have `hash()` return the same type as `finalize()`, `digest::Output<D>`:

```
pub fn hash(&self, data: &[u8]) -> digest::Output<D> {
    (self.digest_factory)()
        .chain(&data)
        .finalize()
}
```

Comment: Perfect, almost exactly what I need. Would be nice to be able to store a digest object to re-use, but I'm okay with constructing a new one for each call. I'll trade that for not copying the digest output to a vector. Thanks!

Comment: Can call `finalize()` instead of `finalize_reset()`, since the object is never reused.

Comment: @theory Good point, I've now amended the answer. I've never used `digest::Digest` so I just went with the code from the question.

Answer (score 2):

To add to [user4815162342's digest factory answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65783589/2766908) here's an alternative implementation using interior mutability:

```rust
use digest::Digest;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Crypto<D: Digest> {
    digest: RefCell<D>,
}

impl<D> Crypto<D>
where
    D: Digest,
{
    pub fn hash(&self, data: &[u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut digest = self.digest.borrow_mut();
        digest.update(&data);
        digest.finalize_reset().to_vec()
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=08d69e3844216f754427621ae0bedf8d)

Comment: Ah, needs to use both RefCell<> and Rc<>, that was the bit I was missing. Thanks! Think I prefer the factory function for overall tidiness, though. Happy to put this in my pocket for the future though.

Comment: Nice - interior mutability is indeed possible if you can get rid of `chain`, which I didn't realize was optional. But why is `digest` an `Rc<RefCell<D>>`? Wouldn't `RefCell<D>` work just as well without the extra heap allocation?

Comment: Just tried that, @user4815162342, and it indeed seems to work fine with `RefCell<D>`.

Comment: @theory It probably didn't work in your original code because you were still calling `chain()` which wanted to consume it - but that wouldn't work with `Rc<RefCell<...>>` either.

Comment: Yes, the fact that `chain()` consumed the struct was the key piece of information to unlock things. I just missed it, and noticed no diagnostics to lead me to it. Thanks for the answers here, I feel better to be done banging my head on this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've updated my answer to only use `RefCell`. The key difference between `RefCell<Digest>` and `Rc<RefCell<Digest>>` would only come into play if you implemented `Clone` for `Crypto`. In the former case the `Digest` instance would be cloned on `Crypto` clones and in the latter case the same `Digest` instance would be shared among all `Crypto` clones, not that it matters in this case since `Crypto` doesn't implement `Clone` but worth mentioning I guess.