# How can the value of the associated types must be specified for a Box<dyn Trait> field?

Tags: dynamic, rust, box, associated-types

I'd like to create a boxed struct field for a trait where the trait has an associated type. Here's an example using [digest::Digest](https://docs.rs/digest/0.9.0/digest/):

```rs
use digest::Digest;
struct Crypto {
    digest: Box<dyn Digest>,
}
```

This fails to compile with the error:

> the value of the associated type `OutputSize` (from trait `digest::Digest`) must be specified

Sometimes I may want to use a [sha2](https://docs.rs/sha2/0.9.2/sha2/)::Sha256 and other times a sha2::Sha512, each with a different `OutputSize`. Is it possible to create a boxed struct field with a dynamic associated type? And if so, how?

Comment: It's a lot easier when you use generics [like you had in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65783417/2766908). Can you please explain in this question why generics no longer work for your use-case and why you're now trying to use boxed trait objects?

Comment: LOL you noticed that, eh? Generics ended up being challenging because I can't create a constructor that returns a Crypto struct with a different digest depending on a runtime configuration value. Even a `fn new() -> Self` that explicitly sets `digest_factory` gives me a mismatched types error ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1bb1b62a6e363d4d8deb534a78dd44fc)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make your own trait and give it a blanket impl across all `Digest` instances that returns `Box<[u8]>` or `Vec<u8>` instead of `GenericArray`, but you don't need to as the authors of `digest` have already created a [`DynDigest`](https://docs.rs/digest/0.9.0/digest/trait.DynDigest.html) trait for you:

```rust
use digest::DynDigest;

struct Crypto {
    digest: Box<dyn DynDigest>,
}
```

Comment: Ah-ha, I see! Need a different trait design to be be effective as a trait object. With that bit of information, I was able to do what I wanted ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d4a946c216e99dc7dd4d4739faafad7c)). Now need to read up on why some traits are suitable for trait objects and others are not.